# How to download data from SNB in R

Tags: r, econometrics

I'd like to download data from the Swiss National Bank (SNB) n R. For instance, let's take data about "Foreign trade by goods category"

https://data.snb.ch/en/topics/aube#!/cube/ausshawarm

In R, a simple function to get .csv data is

```
csv_df <- readr::read_csv('<url>/<filename>.csv')
```

but I don't know how to get SNB data. I click on the CSV(all) on the bottom right, cf. screenshot of what it looks like atm:

[image]

When I download this file (or any other) from SNB and copy the download link, for the instance above, the link copied into the above function would look like this

```
snb <- readr::read_csv('https://data.snb.ch/json/table/getFile?fileId=4878be3d0b1ed65b6a039352dfea7510e6d9c0a41e3b4653f326b9b78f29edfe&pageViewTime=20200228_072727&lang=en')
```

and R can't deal with that, as it doesn't recognize it as a delimited file. I understand there's some JSON magic happening on the server side, but I don't know what to do with and how to work around it.

---

I didn't find other useful tags, so if you read this and would like to suggest one, I encourage you to break your silence and let the class benefit from your knowledge.

I added the econometrics tag, because I guess people in econometrics might have dealt with SNB data and know how to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per instructed on their [API documentation](https://data.snb.ch/en/help#data_api) , try with the following :

```
file <- "https://data.snb.ch/api/cube/ausshawarm/data/csv/en"
snb <- read.table(file, sep = ";", fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: right... I really need to take that API course. It's right there at the top, when one even cares to look at the API documentation. Well, that's gonna be my lesson for the day!